# parent/child CRUD Operations on single MVC5 edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 project using EF6 Code First. It includes models which contain lists of complex child objects. I need to be able to Add, Update, and Delete child objects on the parent objects' Edit page while simultaneously saving changes to the parent object.

I have run into a dilemma in how these operations should be handled in the Controller. Here is the relevant code.

Models:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //other properties
    public virtual IList<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //other properties
    public int Parent_Id {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("Parent_Id")]
    public virtual Parent Parent {get;set;}
    [NotMapped]
    public bool toBeDeleted {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id, Children")] Parent p)
{
    ...
    //For some reason children are brought in with Parent_Id = null.
    //Manually resetting it fixes this issue.
    //Needs to be set before parent = modified for referential integrity
    foreach(var c in p.Children)
    {
        c.Parent_Id = p.Id;
    }
    context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
    for(int i = 0; i < p.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        if(p.c[i].toBeDeleted)
        {
            Child childToDelete = context.Children.Find(p.c[i].Id);
            context.Entry(childToDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(p.c[i]).State = p.c[i].Id > 0 ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
    ...
}
```

I had to include the "i--" after the delete because with the parent being set to modified already, any child objects that were marked for delete were being immediately removed from the list which was throwing the loop off. (I originally had a foreach loop but this problem caused errors when the collection size changed in the middle of the loop)

While what I have works, it feels like a bit of a patchwork fix. It seems to me that there should be a better way to implement this rather than manually decreasing the iterator in a for loop after every delete to keep the items lined up properly. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to set the entity state of each object separately without affecting the state of related objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
p.Children.Where(m => m.toBeDeleted).ToList().ForEach(m => p.Children.Remove(m));
```

By simply removing the children from the collection, Entity Framework will mark them for deletion.

Also, for your add condition, if you've added a hidden field for `Parent_Id` (which you should, if not), then the children will have their `Parent_Id`s set, unless they're new. If they are new, then simply by virtue of being in the `Children` collection of `Parent`, they will be added and the `Parent_Id` property will be set automatically by Entity Framework. Most likely, your problem was in attempting to save existing children that had there `Parent_Id` properties nulled out because it wasn't posted. That will cause an integrity error because it looks to Entity Framework as though you *want* the `Parent_Id` to be changed to null.

Comment: That is pretty cool. The only problem that I noticed is that Remove did not actually delete the objects... it just detached them from the parent. When I queried the database directly, they were still in there with NULL Parent_Id. I played around with it and changed that part to .ForEach(m => context.Entry(m).State = EntityState.Deleted); which seemed to fix that issue. Also, I noticed not long after I posted this that I had forgotten to add a hidden field for the foreign key =) I'll have to modify my AddNew script to set that fields value to what it should be when I add a new child to the page

Comment: Interesting. If it didn't delete them when you removed them from the collection, then that means they're valid on their own: i.e. the `Parent_Id` column is nullable. If they should not ever exist outside of being related to a parent, then you should make sure that's a non-nullable column. Then, they will definitely be deleted if you nix the relationship. However, given that the column is nullable, I have no idea why you received integrity errors previously.

Comment: The integrity issue was due to me forgetting to put the hidden field on the page to hold the Foreign Key for each child. It caused a mismatch between what it thought the relationship should be and what was actually showing. The Delete errors were different and I think were related to how the State was being tracked. You're right though, I do need to re-examine my database relationships; it should not be nullable and the fact that I made it so makes me wonder about all of the many other relationships in the database =\